# Creating a chatbot, but getting an authorisation error when executing with an access token in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, chatbot

Using node and heroku to create a Facebook Messenger bot, I'm up to the webhook stage and trying to implement my access token with the following line

`curl -X POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/me/subscribed_apps?subscribed_fields=publisher_subscriptions&access_token=******`

And command prompt is yielding the error message

```
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"AgbCXm34gHMJtnbxWVJzN5d"}}'access_token' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Am I missing a key part which is leading to an authorisation error?

Comment: Sounds like your access token is expired, so … get a fresh one?

Comment: Btw., it looks like you are throwing two separate error messages together here. The first part is from the Facebook API, but _“'access_token' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.”_ sounds rather like it was from your console or something. (So it could also be that your token is not expired, but you did not correctly pass it with your API call attempt to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks @CBroe, my access token hadn't expired but my issue was that I hadn't closed the quote from the URL. Once this was done, I had an error message that I needed to permissions for pages_manage_metadata - so I submitted a request and once that was done, tried the code again and it yielded {"success"": true} - so happy days!